# Angular nested subscribe code not working as expected

Tags: html, angular, asynchronous, publish-subscribe

My task consists of 2 steps. First step is to retrieve some id data from firestore. Second is to retrieve name data based on the data retrieved in the first step. So I used 1 subscribe for each step. In the code where I am doing console.log() the correct result appears however when the webpage loads the dropdownlist is empty.

```
this.MessagingService.recieveGetClient().subscribe(idData => {
  this.dropdownList = [];
  idData.map((id: string, i: number) => {
    this.VehicleService.getOwnerInfo(id).subscribe(namedata => {
      this.dropdownList.push({ item_id: `${i}`, doc_id: namedata['username'] });
      console.log("this.dropdownList:",this.dropdownList);
    });
  });
});
```

Below is the HTML code. If I get rid of the second subscribe and use id instead of username for dropdownList then it works. But I need to use the username.

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown
    [settings]="dropdownSettings"
    [placeholder]="'Send Message to...'"
    [data]="dropdownList"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedItems"
    (onSelect)="onItemSelect()"
    (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"
    (onDeSelect)="onItemDeSelect()"
    (onDeSelectAll)="onDeSelectAll()"
>
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

Comment: This seems like a good candidate to use [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's multiple subscriptions and mapping data, it's best to use an observable to pipe off the different sources with a switchMap, like this:

```
this.dropdownList$  = this.MessagingService.receiveGetClient()
.pipe(switchMap(id => this.VehicleService.getOwnerInfo(id).pipe(map(nameData => ({id, doc_id: nameData.username})))
));
```

In the template, you can use an async pipe to unwrap the value

```
[data]="dropdownList$ | async"
```

Note that because the async pipe will subscribe, you don't need to manually subscribe in the component or worry about unsubscribing.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot. There is a complication though. In """this.VehicleService.getOwnerInfo(id)""" the id is a list of strings but getOwnerInfo() takes in a string as argument. I am trying to use map to treat the strings individually but unfortunatly it is not working. Can you please help me out.

Comment: I see... I think what you'll need to do then is something like:
switchMap(ids => zip(ids.map(id => this.vehicleService.getOwnerInfo(id).
Check out the rxjs combine operators to deal with waiting for multiple async calls - https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/zip .  Hope that helps

Comment: I put a quick stackblitz doing this in rxjs - https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-gpshqm 
const dropdownList$  = receiveGetClient()
.pipe(switchMap(ids => zip(ids.map(id => getOwnerInfo(id).pipe(map(nameData => ({id, doc_id: nameData.username})))))
));